# Deletes Using Informatica Mapping is taking a very long time

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

we are creating a separate pipeline in the Informatica mapping Designer to handle deletes using the Update Strategy. This is deleting almost 700k records and it is taking almost 24 hours to get completed. the session stats shows that there is a 100 % busy in the writer thread. How to improve the performance?

Comment: Are you using bulk mode? How about using pre- or postsql instead? Have you tried updates to flag the rows and then using post-sql to delete? Please share some more information.

Comment: no we are using Normal mode since the Primary key's are defined in the informatica target definition level itself and we are also using the Update strategy to flag the rows as DD_DELETE .

Comment: pls note, target keys should be defined properly and as per DB indexes.

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not understood globally

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to follow below approach in pre/post sql Of Informatica session.

1. Disable any constraints on target
2. Read the records to be retained into a temp table.
3. Truncate the target table.
4. Insert temp table data to target original table.
5. Enable all constraints.
6. Drop temp table.

When you ask only with Informatica.
Try delete after disabling any constraints if possible. And run Informatica session to delete. Enable constraints.

PS: Beware of playing with constraints. You need to be 100% sure about the data to avoid constraints issues.